# Laravel scope with two relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a main table, "help_pages" which stores id's of either articles or videos. There are two other tables: "articles" and "videos."

In the example below, $portalType is either 'reseller' or 'global' for the purposes of my application. All was well as long as I didn't have a flag on videos to be unpublished. Now I'm having trouble filtering the scope function by BOTH articles and videos that are published.

This is in my models/HelpPage.php:

```
public function scopeByPortalType($query, $portalType) {
    return $query->where('portal_type', '=', $portalType)
    ->leftjoin('articles', 'content_id', '=', 'articles.id')
    ->where('articles.published', '=', '1');
}
```

what I wish I could do is just add a second

```
->leftJoin('videos', 'content_id', '=', videos.id')
->where('videos.published', '=', '0');
```

but this returns too many rows. I tried creating a temp table with a UNION for both articles and videos:

```
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_assets AS 
            (SELECT id, 'Article' AS content_type FROM articles WHERE published = 1)
        UNION
            (SELECT id, 'Video' AS content_type FROM videos WHERE published = 1)
```

and then joining that, but no dice. This might be a smaller deal than I'm making it, but I'm lost now!

Laravel version 4.2

Comment: Do you need to filter the result by the published status or load them. If it is the first you can use the relationship methods instead with scope defined to just to filter by the portal type.

Comment: it needs to filter by published status, and we have other things that wind up getting chained to this, so the filtration needs to happen within that function itself

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not pefect, but it does what I need it to do:

```
public function scopeByPortalType($query, $portalType) {
    $q = $query
        ->whereRaw("
        (id IN (SELECT help_pages.id FROM help_pages INNER JOIN articles ON content_id=articles.id WHERE articles.published='1' AND content_type='Article')
        OR
        id IN (SELECT help_pages.id FROM help_pages INNER JOIN videos ON content_id=videos.id WHERE videos.published='1' AND content_type='Video'))")
        ->where('portal_type', '=', $portalType);
    return $q;
}
```

I wish I could've figured out a way to do it using actual Eloquent, but every step led me down a rabbit hole with a dead end. This worked!

Answer (score 0):

The Eloquent way to do this would be setting up the relationships so you could utilize eager loading.

Relationships: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Eager Loading: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Setup relations:

```
class HelpPage extends Eloquent {

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Article');
    }


    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Video');
    }

}
```

Then you can utilize eager loading like this:

```
$help_pages = HelpPage::with(array('articles' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('published', '=', 1);

},
'videos' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('published', '=', 1);

}
))->get();
```

You might be able to then leverage whereHas and orWhereHas on the actual query rather than my example above.

Comment: I did wind up trying that, but for some reason it wouldn't actually filter it just returned everything...?

Comment: Right, my example would pull all of the articles that were set to `published = 1`, you can update that query to further narrow down the results. Just before the get() you can add your `->where('portal_type', '=', $portalType)`. That should return you all of the help_pages with that portal type with two sub arrays `articles` and `videos` that are `published = 1`. If that is not what you want, can you give an example of the dataset you would like to see returned?

Comment: Ah, yes. This is the correct answer, however in order to make my code backwards-compatible with other code (the whole section was built by someone else before we had a thorough understanding of laravel), I had to go with the whereRaw example I posted. I will heed your advice for new, future functions- thanks!